# Capistrano 3 rails deploy cant find database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, capistrano3

DigitalOcean Ubuntu 14.04 x64 + Rails 4 + Nginx + Unicorn + PostgreSQL + Capistrano 3

I used this walkthrough to deploy my digital ocean rails app.

https://gist.github.com/ChuckJHardy/f44dda5f94c6bbdba9a4

The instructions are very clear and too the point so I did not have to deviate from the walkthrough.

I have finished everything and when i run

```
cap production deploy:check
```

there are no errors. But when I run

```
cap production deploy
```

It crashes saying

```
INFO [deploy:migrate] Checking changes in /db/migrate
DEBUG [87821ebd] Running /usr/bin/env diff -q /home/deployer/apps/jones_jems/releases/20150506224711/db/migrate /home/deployer/apps/jones_jems/current/db/migrate as deployer@107.170.222.154
DEBUG [87821ebd] Command: diff -q /home/deployer/apps/jones_jems/releases/20150506224711/db/migrate /home/deployer/apps/jones_jems/current/db/migrate
DEBUG [87821ebd]    diff: 
DEBUG [87821ebd]    /home/deployer/apps/jones_jems/current/db/migrate
DEBUG [87821ebd]    : No such file or directory
DEBUG [87821ebd]    
DEBUG [87821ebd] Finished in 0.085 seconds with exit status 2 (failed).
INFO [deploy:migrate] Run `rake db:migrate`
DEBUG [b41648f9] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /home/deployer/apps/jones_jems/releases/20150506224711; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deployer/apps/jones_jems/releases/20150506224711'" 1>&2; false; fi as deployer@107.170.222.154
DEBUG [b41648f9] Command: if test ! -d /home/deployer/apps/jones_jems/releases/20150506224711; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deployer/apps/jones_jems/releases/20150506224711'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [b41648f9] Finished in 0.074 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [bde04a76] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake db:migrate as deployer@107.170.222.154
DEBUG [bde04a76] Command: cd /home/deployer/apps/jones_jems/releases/20150506224711 && ( RAILS_ENV=production ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake db:migrate )
DEBUG [bde04a76]    rake aborted!
DEBUG [bde04a76]    ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  database "JonesJems" does not exist
```

I followed the walkthrough on creating the database listed below

**Create Postgres User**

```
sudo -u postgres psql
create user deployer with password 'password';
alter role deployer superuser createrole createdb replication;
create database JonesJems owner deployer;
```

If i try to do this walkthrough again it says the says the database already exists.

```
postgres=# create database JonesJems owner deployer;
ERROR:  database "jonesjems" already exists
```

Here is my rails database.yml file

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 5432
  encoding: unicode
  database: JonesJems
  pool: 5
  username: <%= ENV['JJ_DB_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['JJ_DB_PASSWORD'] %>
```

with the env variables being stored in etc/environment

Answer (score 2):

I ended up just running rake db:create in on of the release directories

Comment: And if you're doing it on the production server then run: `$ RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create`

Answer (score -1):

I see the database.yml file and the ActiveRecord error message both refer to the database name as `JonesJems` (title case), whereas the psql error refers to `jonesjems` (lower case).

Perhaps the ActiveRecord database adapter is case sensitive with respect to database names?

Try changing the production.yml to `database: jonesjems`.

Comment: ya I noticed that and tried it too. I created the database with the name JonesJems. I have also tried using different users for the database admin but I have listed the databases and I can see jonesjems along with the correct owner.